# Lucene .NET IndexWriter DeleteDocuments Not Working

Tags: .net, lucene, lucene.net

Here is the code:

```
Try
        Dim util As New IndexerUtil()
        Dim dir As Lucene.Net.Store.Directory = FSDirectory.Open(New DirectoryInfo(util.getIndexDir()))
        Dim indexWriter As New IndexWriter(dir, New SimpleAnalyzer(), indexWriter.MaxFieldLength.UNLIMITED)

        Dim numDocs As Integer = indexWriter.NumDocs()

        indexWriter.DeleteDocuments(New Term("id", insightId))
        indexWriter.Optimize()
        indexWriter.Commit()
        indexWriter.Close()
        numDocs = indexWriter.NumDocs()

    Catch ex As Exception
        LOG.Error("Could not remove insight " + insightId + " from index", ex)
    End Try
```

numDocs = 85 both times

I also have a little gui app I wrote which reads the index and prints the docs out in a nice format. The doc with the id field that equals insightId definitely exists and STILL exists after the "deletion".

Here is how the id field is being created

```
doc.Add(New Field("id", insightID, Field.Store.YES, Field.Index.ANALYZED)) //insightID is an integer
```

Comment: How are you creating the id field when you build the index? Could you post the code of that? Also, does the code throw any exceptions?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As you have probably discovered with your [more recent post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6538446/lucene-net-not-returning-search-results), your ID column is not being indexed correctly because [SimpleAnalyzer](http://lucene.apache.org/java/2_2_0/api/org/apache/lucene/analysis/SimpleAnalyzer.html) uses [LetterTokenizer](http://lucene.apache.org/java/2_2_0/api/org/apache/lucene/analysis/LetterTokenizer.html), which only returns letters.

Consider using the [KeywordAnalyzer](http://lucene.apache.org/java/2_2_0/api/org/apache/lucene/analysis/KeywordAnalyzer.html) instead for the `id` field.

Comment: If the id field is an integer and it's probably only used for keeping track of documents wouldn't it be better to store it as `NOT_ANALYZED` field, instead? This way he wouldn't have to worry about analyzers at all.

Comment: @George, you're probably right.  The OP will still need an appropriate analyzer if he'll be parsing a query that contains `id:1234`, but that's usually in a much different area of code.

Comment: I thought so, but I wanted to be sure. Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

Since SimpleAnalyzer converts input text to lowercase, you will have lowercased terms in the index.
Are you sure that "insightId" is also lowercased?

Comment: The insightId is an integer value (I convert it to a string) so there is no upper/lower case.

Answer (score 0):

You should create a new IndexWriter instead of counting documents on a closed one.

Comment: Yeah I realized that after posting this. However, that still does not change the fact the document(s) are NOT being deleted.